# How to compose with center gravity in PythonMagick

Tags: python, pythonmagick

I did appreciate [the answer by Orbling on `.composite()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17282525/1346705):

```
flattened.composite(img, 0, 0, PythonMagick.CompositeOperator.SrcOverCompositeOp)
```

This is the form where the second image is placed to the (0, 0) coordinates of the original image. I tried, but I could not find how the image could be centered to the original.

The internal `__doc__` says (formatted manually):

```
composite( (Image)arg1, 
           (Image)arg2, 
           (GravityType)arg3 
           [, (CompositeOperator)arg4]) -> None :

C++ signature :
    void composite(class Magick::Image {lvalue},
                   class Magick::Image,
                   enum MagickCore::GravityType 
                   [,enum MagickCore::CompositeOperator])
```

How should I enter the 3rd argument in Python code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(You know, sometimes the answer is obvious when you formulate the question precisely.)

The solution is:

```
flattened.composite(img, 
                    PythonMagick.GravityType.CenterGravity,            # this
                    PythonMagick.CompositeOperator.SrcOverCompositeOp)
```